# ¿Nunca se les ocurre que esto les ocurra/ocurriría?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Quiero traducir la siguiente frase inglesa usando solo el verbo *ocurrir(se)*:

> It never occurs to them that this would/might happen to them.

Me parece que el negativo de la primera parte de la frase exige el subjuntivo en la segunda parte, así

> No se les ocurre que esto les ocurra.

sin embargo me suena un poco "mejor" el condicional

> No se les ocurre que esto les ocurriría.

es decir, más como la frase original, aunque pueda ser una traducción demasiado literal del inglés. Si la segunda frase es correcta, quería saber por qué no se exige el subjuntivo aquí.

Comment: Yo lo diría "No se les ocurre que esto les **podría** ocurrir" donde _podría_ cumple la función de _might_. Lo anterior conservando las palabras que quieres usar, pero en lenguaje más común para mi diría "no se les ocurre que esto les **podría pasar**"

Comment: or also "que les pudiera pasar", depending on if you're absolutely certain it will happen, or not.

Comment: *Nunca* se les ocurre que esto les podría pasar.

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @Dgaleano the phrase sounds better with a podría, so you could translate the:

> It never occurs to them that this would/might happen to them.

into something like:

> No se les ocurre que esto les podría pasar

And generalizing the answer, there are some phrases of general usage for that like:

> Nadie escarmienta en cabeza ajena

That means like: You have to do the things to feel the consequences

Comment: "Y a-t-il quelqu'un de si sage pour apprendre par l’expérience des autres ? Voltaire. ("Is there anyone so wise as to learn by the experience of others?")   :-)

Answer (score 2):

No creo que la negativa tenga nada que ver con el subjuntivo, en todo caso el verbo auxiliar (*would*) es lo que define el tiempo del segundo ocurra (*happen*) y el tiempo correspondiente es el pospretérito o condicional. Según la definición:

> ubican la acción expresada por el verbo en un punto que resulta anterior al momento de la expresión, aunque posterior a otro instante del pasado.
> En el caso específico del condicional simple o pospretérito, la acción se expresa como si aún no hubiese terminado. Es habitual que el pospretérito se utilice para hacer referencia a un acontecimiento hipotético.

Aqui *happen* sería el hecho hipotético. Entonces lo más natural sería "ocurriría" (*would* implícito) o "podría ocurrir(les)" (*would* explícito). Por otra parte no es ideal repetir verbos porque se considera cacofónico. La traducción más natural para mí sería:

> Nunca se les ocurre que eso podría pasar(les)

[Modo subjuntivo](https://www.academia.org.mx/espin/respuestas/item/el-modo-subjuntivo)

[Definición de pospretérito](https://definicion.de/pospreterito/)

Comment: Claro, esta traducción es la buena. Hay que poner "nunca."

Comment: De acuerdo con el nunca, sin embargo tengo dudas con el sentido de la frase.
¿Por qué no decir "Nunca se les ocurre que eso puede pasar/suceder/ocurrir"? Puede en lugar de podría.

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, _podría_ es más especulativo que _puede_. Además _puede_ podría ser ambiguo. Pueden checar el ejemplo [https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/514-puede-podria ](aqui) : "Puede pasarle a cualquiera — It could/can happen to anyone (Ambiguo en español: 1. es algo que ocurre a veces o 2. es algo potencial que podría ocurrir)
→Podría pasarle a cualquiera — It could happen to anyone (Aclara que se refiere a algo potencial; igual no ha ocurrido todavía)